# Prevent redirection in Django template form

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, django-templates

Currently, my application is rendering an Django Template model form wherein some images are referred from another model.

In order to delete and add images for the other model, I am handling it with a button with an overriden `formaction` that points to a DRF-based REST endpoint which deals with the images.

However, whenever the service is invoked, it redirects the app to API response page. I would like to if it is possible to prevent redirection after `formaction` for button or input html elements

Comment: It would be useful if you could add a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) extract of your code showing the problem,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once *formaction* is invoked, redirection redirection is unavoidable. We can use `preventDefault()` of the element to customize the behaviour but that is a poor practice. A good way to resolve it would be to invoke the request within a JS function and handle it as desired without tying it to a specific element